# Read variable from file in target recipe enclosed in foreach

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a top level Makefile that can create multiple targets, for which I have a for loop in place. In this file I am trying to read a text file with a version number that is created only when a sub makefile runs. I have got it to work but it looks very ugly, so I'm thinking there is possibly a better way to do it. Here is the top level Makefile:

```
T1=_release
T2=_debug
T3=_test


all: bin/mybin_release.bin
debug: bin/mybin_debug.bin
debug: export DBG:=1
test: bin/mybin_test.bin
test: export TST:=1

define build_foo

bin/mybin$$($(1)).bin: bin/abc$$($(1)).bin bin/xyz$$($(1)).bin
    cat $$^ > $$@
    VER=$$$$(cat bin/rev.txt) && mv bin/mybin$$($(1)).bin bin/mybin$$($(1))_$$$${VER}.bin

bin/abc$$($(1)).bin:
    $(MAKE) -C mod1    # <--- rev.txt is produced here

bin/xyz$$($(1)).bin:
    $(MAKE) -C mod2

endef

$(foreach suffix, T1 T2 T3, $(eval $(call build_foo,$(suffix))))

clean:
    rm bin/*.bin bin/*.txt
```

Notice the attempt to grab file contents in `VER`. Is there a better/right way to do this? I cannot use `eval` since it runs at the beginning and `rev.txt` only gets created once the sub make runs.
Also, is this a decent way to build multiple targets(using foreach)? I use the exported variables to modify the target built by the sub makefile.

Comment: How is `bin/rev.txt` produced? What if it already exists? What if all the `bin/abcXXX.bin` and `bin/xyzXXX.bin` already exist and `bin/rev.txt` does not exist?

Comment: rev.txt gets produced by the sub make run in `mod1/`. It does not exist when the top level Makefile is run. I added that clarification in the question.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, this `bin/rev.txt` file, and all the `bin/abcXXX.bin` are produced when running `$(MAKE) -C mod1`. So, it is the same for all. What about:

```
include version.mk

version.mk: bin/rev.txt
    { printf 'VER = '; cat $<; } > $@

bin/rev.txt:
    $(MAKE) -C mod1
```

Demo:

```
$ ls
Makefile
$ cat Makefile
include version.mk

all:
    touch $(VER).txt

version.mk: rev.txt
    { printf 'VER = '; cat $<; } > $@

rev.txt:
    echo "1.2.3" > $@
$ make --quiet
Makefile:1: version.mk: No such file or directory
$ ls
1.2.3.txt  Makefile  rev.txt  version.mk
```

Explanation:

`version.mk` is a second makefile that make will look for. As per [GNU make documentation, section 3.5](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Remaking-Makefiles):

> To this end, after reading in all makefiles, make will consider each
>   as a goal target and attempt to update it. If a makefile has a rule
>   which says how to update it (found either in that very makefile or in
>   another one) or if an implicit rule applies to it (see Using Implicit
>   Rules), it will be updated if necessary. After all makefiles have been
>   checked, if any have actually been changed, make starts with a clean
>   slate and reads all the makefiles over again. (It will also attempt to
>   update each of them over again, but normally this will not change them
>   again, since they are already up to date.)

Note: as you wrote your makefile, `$(MAKE) -C mod1` will be run several times, which is a waste. You could instead exploit a specificity of GNU make pattern rules: when they have multiple targets, make considers that all targets are produced by one single invocation of the recipe. Example:

```
$ cat Makefile
all: a.bin b.bin c.bin

a.%in b.%in c.%in:
    @echo 'building a.bin b.bin c.bin'
$ make all
building a.bin b.bin c.bin
```

See? The recipe is executed only once to build the 3 targets. The only problem is that the `%` wildcard must match at least one character. So, in your case you could do something like (the character that `%` matches is the `b` of `bin/`):

```
T1        := _release
T2        := _debug
T3        := _test
suffixes  := T1 T2 T3
pattern   := $(foreach suffix,$(suffixes),%in/abc$($(suffix))) %in/rev.txt

$(pattern):
    $(MAKE) -C mod1
```

This will tell make that `$(MAKE) -C mod1` builds all the `bin/abcXXX.bin` and `bin/rev.txt` at once. Same with `$(MAKE) -C mod2`.

All in all, you could probably get completely rid of your `build_foo` generic rule by gluing all these features together. Something like:

```
T1         := _release
T2         := _debug
T3         := _test
suffixes   := T1 T2 T3
patternabc := $(foreach suffix,$(suffixes),%in/abc$($(suffix)).bin) %in/rev.txt
patternxyz := $(foreach suffix,$(suffixes),%in/xyz$($(suffix)).bin)

include version.mk

all:   bin/mybin_release_$(VER).bin
debug: bin/mybin_debug_$(VER).bin
debug: export DBG:=1
test:  bin/mybin_test_$(VER).bin
test:  export TST:=1

version.mk: bin/rev.txt
    { printf 'VER = '; cat $<; } > $@

$(patternabc):
    $(MAKE) -C mod1

$(patternxyz):
    $(MAKE) -C mod2

bin/mybin%_$(VER).bin: bin/abc%.bin bin/xyz%.bin
    cat $^ > $@
```